# passing prop server-side is not being rendered client-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pug

The following node.js code is rendering my `App` component with a prop...

```
var reactHtml = reactDom.renderToString(App({exists: true}));
res.render('../../tutorHub/views/index.jade', {reactOutput: reactHtml});
```

And this component is caught by my jade file as so...

```
#app != reactOutput
```

Now in the component itself, I'm checking to see if the prop is rendered...

```
render(){

        console.log(this.props.exists);
...
...
```

When I run this through my terminal, the console prints out `true`. However, in my browser terminal I get `undefined`, meaning react is re-rendering the component on the client side after the prop is set.

I am desperately trying to find a fix to this, I do not want to have to restructure my entire website. Can someone help me fix this?

Do I need to prevent the re-rendering somehow?

EDIT

So in my node.js file I did the following...

```
var reactHtml = reactDom.renderToString(App({}));
res.render('../../tutorHub/views/index.jade', {reactOutput: reactHtml, errorExist:true});
```

In my jade file I did the following...

```
#app != reactOutput

script(type='text/javascript')                                                   
    window.data =!{JSON.stringify(errorExist)};
```

But now I tried to retrieve the data in my component...

```
if (window.data) {
        return (
            <Register />

            );
        }
        else {
            return (
            <Index event={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />

            );
        }
```

But I get error `window` and `data` `are not defined`.

Comment: Have you double checked to see whether or not the client also passes the same set of properties when rendering? Re-rendering on the front-end is actually perfectly normal. What you need is a near perfect one-to-one mapping between client and server for the data. One trick would be to embed the data directly with the HTML, somewhere (maybe a script tag with the data encoded in JSON).

Comment: @SalehenRahman I see, what exactly do you mean by embed data directly, do you have an example or something?

Comment: It would pretty much look like this in your Jade code: `script = JSON.stringify(myData)`.

Comment: Then, right before when the client renders the app, you would grab the data from the script tag, and pass them as property, when rendering.

Comment: @SalehenRahman Ok So I tried your approach, Im stuck on one part, can you see my edit? Thanks

Comment: In your edit, where is `data` defined? Is it before the React render, or is it after? The other thing you might try, instead of declaring `data` as a variable, assign a property `data` onto the global `window` variable, so that `data` is available pretty much everywhere.e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets call `{exists: true}` the initial state.

**1. On the server:** Serialize the initial state using `JSON.stringify` and store it in the jade template.

*node.js*

```
var reactHtml = reactDom.renderToString(App({exists: true}));
res.render('../../tutorHub/views/index.jade', {
  reactOutput: reactHtml, 
  initialState: JSON.stringify({exists: true})
});
```

*jade file*

```
#app != reactOutput

#initialState =! initialState
```

**2. On the client:** Get the initial state from the DOM and deserialize it using `JSON.parse` in the [`getInitialState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#getinitialstate) lifecycle method of the `App` react component

*App react component*

```
getInitialState() {
  return JSON.parse(document.getElementById('initialState').innerHTML)
}
```

3. The `exists` boolean is now accessible in the `App` components state through `this.state.exists`

Comment: I tried your way but I get `document is not defined` error, why is that?

Comment: Please add check to `getInitialState` to detect if `document` is available. It won't render on the server.

Something like `if (typeof document === 'undefined') return {};`

Comment: From what I know is that in server side render, browser window is not created still, and so the `document` object is not available, neither the `window`.